# What was the "undocumented and incredibly non-performant way to monitor setting and getting of values"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, deprecated

The [jQuery Core 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#events-not-fired-by-the-data-method-names-with-periods) says, ".data() method had an undocumented and incredibly non-performant way to monitor setting and getting of values that was removed in 1.9."

What was this?

I'm not asking so I can use it, but so I can grep and make sure it's not used (I'm fairly certain it's not in my code base, but perhaps someone else's code does have it without them knowing.).

Comment: use a diff tool to see what changed between versions

Answer (score 0):

I think we're talking about event monitoring here. Try this:

```
<span id="fapfap">fap</span>

<script>
$(function(){
  $("#fapfap").click(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text()+"fap")
  });

  console.log($("#fapfap").data("events.click"));
});
```

In older jq versions you'll see an event object

Comment: Further to that... There's a much better explanation than mine here http://www.elijahmanor.com/how-to-access-jquerys-internal-data/

Comment: I get undefined, even in jQuery 1.8.3: http://jsfiddle.net/9kh9ywLq/1/ .  Also, I am asking about something from the 1.9 release notes, whereas that link says, "as of jQuery 1.7 the whole event system was rewritten from the ground up.", so it seems you're referring to a separate feature that was removed earlier.

I think the 1.9 release notes are talking about a way to monitor usage of .data in general.